# Webkit filters not playing nicely with overflows

Tags: css, webkit, overflow, css-filters

I've got an element that gets the following:

`-webkit-filter: blur(15px) contrast(120%) brightness(110%);`

I have another element that overlays it with a little area to scroll some photos - in the end, it looks like this:

[image]

In order to scroll the photos horizontally, I use the following CSS:

```
  .photos {
    height: 110px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;

    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
```

The problem I am having is that when I apply `overflow-x: scroll;` (or any overflow declaration) and then do *anything* it janks and the filter gets all weird with the elements. In this example, I've scrolled the photos a little:

[image]

As you can see... something goes wrong. I understand that applying a filter to the background and then moving content overtop of it is probably pretty tough for the browser to do, and this is perhaps why it's happening. What I'm wondering is if anyone has found a way for it to work.

Any advice is much appreciated.

**Edit**

Here is a fiddle I made up demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/d8THd/1/

**Edit 2**

Here's a video! https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmop991qud7np6i/BlurJank.mov

Comment: Could you post your complete code / a fiddle? Also, would it work for you to apply the filter directly to the photos themselves?  I tried that quickly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/9t4eE/1/), and while the filters are (as always) a tiny bit wonky, it seems to mostly work.

Comment: @RyanMitchell I've updated the question with a fiddle demo - I think there was a misunderstanding with my question; it's actually the background that gets the filter, not the top images. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle; that makes more sense. I don't see the problem in up-to-date Chrome (36) for Windows. Which Webkit browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: I'm running Chrome 36 on Mac - here's a video of what is going on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmop991qud7np6i/BlurJank.mov

Comment: Looking at the video, the bug seems to occur at those places where the opacity is less than 1 (the bg, the scrollbar, etc.)--it seems to be a rendering bug where it miscalculates the color values of what lies underneath the non-opaque content. I'm not sure what the solution is, however--all I can offer is the small consolation that your Windows Chrome users won't encounter the bug.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. That's lame. I wonder if this is something that I should file a bug for?

Comment: I thought of one more thing. Sometimes Webkit problems with transformations can be fixed by adding `backface-visibility: hidden` to elements that get distorted. Not sure it will work in your case, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Interesting - I'll try it out! Thanks!